# SAS table created from Oracle DB can't be loaded into CAS VIYA

Tags: oracle, sas, blob, cas

i'm trying to Import SAS table with one BLOB column ( multiple rows) in SAS VIYA problem

imported into sas table from ORACLE sql, but when trying to load into CAS = Error message =

> ERROR: BASE Data Connector, Cross Environment Data Access (CEDA)
>   translation failed. Some character data was lost during transcoding
>   while loading the table. Either the data contains characters that are
>   not representable in the new encoding or truncation occurred during
>   transcoding. The charMultiplier= import option may prevent the error.
>   ERROR: BASE Data Connector failed.**

```
libname TOLOCAL 'C:\me\temporary\tables';
proc sql outobs=50;
CONNECT USING BAS AS ORAC;
create table TOLOCAL.outtable as
select PDFFILE from BAS.BAS_DUR
 DISCONNECT FROM ORAC;
QUIT;
```

I would like to create a SAS table with BLOB's that will be ready to be loaded in VIYA 
(CAS) without that error.
The procedure to load is just by clicling into the SASTABLE in viya and trying to load it in memory.

Comment: Did you try using `PROC FEDSQL` instead to get support for VARCHAR data type? Normal SAS datasets can only try to store the BLOB as a fixed length character strings which has a limit of 32k bytes.

Comment: 1) Hi, Thank you for the message, it was an encoding problem, and yes, they are >32K...., even if I load the blobs, it I can't process them ., the sas table was recreated from oracle outside VIya but when i tried to load it into Viya's CAS, I found this message..
 2) i'm looking for ways to load pdf's ( and covert them) into TA in Viya